# Two inline rotated text snippets

Tags: math-mode, rotating

I want to achieve this (in math mode):

[image: example]

*blabla* will be something like `\foreach x`, *c1* and *c2* `\supset A`, `\subset B`, and *lalala* the rest of the formula.

What's the best way to achieve this? I'm thinking of using _ and ^, together with rotatebox.

edit: this solution looks like:

[image: example2]

Comment: Instead of using this, have you considered reformulating the expression so that this rotated elements are not required?

Comment: Yes, but my formulas are very long. Do you have a suggestion? Perhaps making it all one line, and bolding the variable I'm quantifying over?

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    $\forall x_{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-20}{$\ \subseteq B$}}\hspace{-2.5em}^{\rotatebox[origin=c]{20}{$\ \supseteq A$}}\ lalala$
\end{document}
```

This produces result

[image: here]

If you don't like the manual space adjusments, look into overlaping.

Edited: code that yeilds better result.

Answer (score 3):

Some improvement of the solution proposed bu @Kiraa.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
$\forall x
\lower .5em \hbox{%
  \rotatebox[origin=lB]{-30}{$\supseteq A$}%
}%
\llap{%
 \lower -.5em \hbox{%
   \rotatebox[origin=lb]{30}{$\subseteq B$}%
 }%
}%
\exists y \in C$
\end{document}
```

[image]